# Is it correct to say "human first" (or "human-first")?

Tags: grammaticality, expressions

I'm not native English and some work colleague and me were discussing about if saying *human first* or *human-first* is a correct English expression.

For example, we may promote that our company thinks of humans before machines so we might say:

- **Human first**. We prioritize human development, because we love our job. Customer satisfaction starts with our own work happiness.

It's just a sample sentence to provide an use case of *human first*.

Is it correct?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Actually there is already  a job consulting  firm  that uses that expression in their name.

Comment: Human first is fine. What's not fine is thinking in humans. That makes no sense. You can think in categories, in pictures, in symbols; in terms, in ways; in hindsight, in advance; but you cannot think in humans. You think *of* humans.

Comment: @Josh61 Yeah, I found that, BTW sometimes company names aren't correct in terms of language rules.

Comment: @ЯegDwight I see! Why don't you post a an answer for that? I'll be glad to upvote/accept it :)

Comment: **If** you are promoting the company and want to mean that you give priority to humans over machines, **human first is absolutely fine**. Go ahead with it. Just no hyphen.

Comment: @MaulikV Nice! Thank you, it would be nice that you add the whole comment as an answer so I can upvote it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not "correct" to say **Human first**. Certainly in any normal context it wouldn't be considered a credible "sentence". The nearest equivalent I can think of is...

> [*Women and children first*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22women%20and%20children%20first%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

...which is essentially an [imperative](http://www.englishgrammarsecrets.com/imperative/menu.php) command reduced from something like *"**Let** women and children **go** first"*, or *"**Put** women and children first **in priority**"*. *Grammatically*, the equivalent for *human* should probably be...

> *Humanity first*
>    or
>    *Human beings first*

Note that the *women and children* version is idiomatically well-established, and actually *means* something in real-world contexts (emergencies such as a shipwrecks). In practice, OP's version is simply [*marketese*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/marketese) (a marketing slogan), so it doesn't need to "mean" anything, or adhere to any grammatical principles.

It's also worth pointing out that *syntactically*, ***human*** is normally an adjective. It *can* be used as a (countable) noun, in which case in functions similarly to ***woman, child, person***. I suppose given the way [Toys R Us](http://www.toysrus.co.uk/index.jsf) tramples over standard grammar and orthography, they could feasibly adopt a slogan such as *"**Child first**"*. In *language* terms it would be "weird", but at least it might grab people's attention.

Comment: So I need to understand that *human first* is ok when it's applied to a marketing slogan. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Matías: I'm not sure what you mean by "ok" there. Personally I think as a marketing slogan it stinks (*and* it sounds to me like a bad translation, rather than something a native speaker working for an advertising agency might come up with). Opinions on marketing material are outside the scope of ELL, but for what it's worth I would sooner buy from a company using the byline *"We put people first"*, rather than *"Human first"*. But in reality we all know *companies* are in it for *profit* - no-one believes "corporate messages" like that anyway, but you really need to do some market research.

Comment: Well, in fact "We put people first" is a good idea. It sounds good.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer whoa whoa... *we put people first* is a **very** popular tagline. Be cautious before you use it professionally!

Comment: @Maulik: Yes, but we're not here to provide marketing advice. The reason *"We put people first"* (and variants such as *you, the customer, quality, satisfaction*, etc.) are very popular is precisely *because* such constructions are syntactically "normal" and don't just sound quirky/stupid.

Comment: @MaulikV Well, but I was going to use *People first* instead of *Human first*.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I can still find a clear difference between *people first* and *human first.* Both are not same (at least to me!) in marketing. Anyway, as FumbleFingers said, we aren't here to discuss marketing. :)

Comment: While the answer is correct, I can see *"a human-first approach"* being used. It's still marketing-speak, but when used in the context of "[hu]man vs machine" it is at least correct. Something like *"In this time of technological advancement and redefinition of the roles of man and machine, we take the human-first approach."* But that is admittedly a highly contrived example.

Comment: @Jonathan: I take your point that that's a highly contrived example, where the ***man** and machine* contrast steers us closer to accepting ***human*** (if only because *"the **man-first** approach"* is a weirding too far! :). But I still bet if you presented your entire italicised sentence to 1000 native speakers with *"the **XXXX-first** approach"*, and asked them what word would fit best, the majority would go with ***people***, not ***human***.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually several different issues with the proposed statement which need to be addressed:

### "Human first" vs. "Humans first"

The first question that comes to mind when reading "human first" is "which human?".  Is only one human being put first?  If the answer is yes, then you probably need to specify more precisely which one:

> "Put that human first," said the robot overlord to the executioner.

The answer is probably no, though, and you really meant to put all humans first, in which case "humans" needs to be plural here:

> The angry mob shouted, "Humans first!"

### Is "humans first" a valid sentence?

No.  There is no verb here, so you can't just use it by itself as a sentence.  A proper sentence should say something like "Humans **should come** first."

It is common in some circumstances (slogans, headlines, etc) to leave verbs out of sentences when the meaning can be understood without them.  This can be done for emphasis or convenience (when chanting a slogan), or to save space (when writing on signs or printing newspaper headlines).  It is also sometimes done in advertising.  It's important to note, however, that while this is *common*, it is still *not grammatically correct*, and should not be done in more formal contexts.  A more correct way to write your text would be:

> Humans should come first. We prioritize human development, because we love our job. Customer satisfaction starts with our own work happiness.

### Period vs. Colon

Using a period to separate the first sentence from the rest of the statement is technically OK, but since the first bit is serving as an introduction to the rest of the text, arguably a better choice here would be a colon:

> Humans should come first: We prioritize human development, because we love our job. Customer satisfaction starts with our own work happiness.

### When to use hyphenated phrases

Regarding "humans first" vs. "humans-first", connecting words with a hyphen changes them into an adjective (or sometimes an adverb), which means they then need to be used to describe something else:

> We believe in putting humans first.

("humans" (noun) are being "put" (verb) "first" (adjective))

vs.

> We have a humans-first attitude.

("humans-first" (adjective) is a modifier of "attitude" (noun))

Comment: I appreciate your answer. It adds more value to the issue itself. In the other hand, it seems like "XXX first" in marketing is accepted, isn't it? Your sentences may be too long if they need to be used as a marketing slogan. Anyway, I agree that our discussion isn't about marketing, but just about English correctness :)

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned things like that are done sometimes  (and even possibly considered accepted) in advertising/marketing, but that still doesn't mean that they're correct :)  In some cases it makes sense due to space concerns, or needing to make the rhythm or sound of a phrase work better, but in other cases it's really just sloppiness and people should still hold it up as a bad practice...

Comment: At the end of the day, it's like poetry or music: the language is turned into art